# Why won't setMatrix([...matrix, [[x][y]]]) work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to add the coordinates `x` and `y` (from the loop) to the state (`matrix`) like you can see in my example but it won't work. Can someone help me?

```
const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState([[], []] as any)

for (let j = 0; j < imgHeight * scale; j += props.gridsize.height) {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgWidth * scale; i += props.gridsize.width) {
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' ===== ' + 'y: ' + y)
    drawImgRectangles(ctx, [{ x: x, y: y, width: props.gridsize.width, height: props.gridsize.height }])
    x += props.gridsize.height

  }
  x = 0
  y += props.gridsize.height
}
setMatrix([...matrix, [[x][y]]])
console.log(matrix[[0][0]]) **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in expression `[x][y]` which evaluates to undefined.

- `[x]` defines an array containing one element `x`
- `[x][y]` tries to index the `[x]` array, taking `y`-th element. If y is anything other than 0, the result is `undefined`

```
console.log([3][0]);  // 3
console.log([3][1]);  // undefined
```

You probably meant one of:

```
const x = 1;
const y = 2;

var matrix1: number[][] = [];
matrix1 = [...matrix1, [x, y]];

var matrix2: number[][][] = [];
matrix2 = [...matrix2, [[x], [y]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the first step.
And the example I was able to implement :)